# Sequences of rapidly decaying analytic functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Note that we have 
$$\frac{1}{x}\gg\frac{1}{x^2}\gg\frac{1}{x^3}\gg\cdots\gg e^{-x}.$$

I was wondering if a generalization is possible.  Namely, if $f_1\gg f_2\gg f_3\gg\cdots$ are analytic from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, then does there always exist some analytic $f \not \equiv 0$ s.t. $f_n\gg f$ $\forall n$?

Edit:  By $f\gg g$ I mean $g/f \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: I think Theorem VI in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3801) may be relevant. But I don't have the time to try and replicate the construction now for your case.

Comment: We might want to try something dumb such as interpolating the points $(n, f_n(n))$ by an analytic function $h$ (Yes, I am invocating a diagonal argument here). If we can somehow bound the derivative of $h$, then this would solve the problem. However, we would need to write $h$ as a (limit of) linear combination of some rapidly decreasing sequence of analytic functions <looks hungrily in the general direction of the $(f_n)$ sequence>.